# Can't get .clone() to work

Tags: jquery, clone

This might be a silly question but I've been trying to copy a div (`div.frame`) 8 times into its parent (`div#game`) but its not working.

**EDIT** : The `div.frame` is not copied at all. Even `console.log(frameClone);` shows weird result

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/utZRJ/1/)

---

**jQuery**

```
(function($) {
    var $game1 = $('div#game1');
    var frameClone = $('div.frame').clone();

    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        // frameClone.appendTo('div#game1');
        // frameClone.appendTo($game1);
        // $game1.append(frameClone[0]);
        // $game1.append(frameClone);
        // none of these work
    }

    var $frame = $('div.frame');

})(jQuery);
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="game1">
    <!-- this is one frame. Its cloned and repeated 8 more times -->
    <div data-win="-" class="frame">
        <div class="winsign"></div>
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What part isn't working?

Comment: That's not really a DOM ready handler, it's a "wrap jQuery" execute now function.

Comment: @adeneo: Which is fine, as long as it's *after* the elements it relies on. The fiddle uses `onload`, which is jsFiddle's brain-dead default, no way to know if the OP's is in the right order or not...

Comment: @adeneo You were right. My `script` tag was in `head`. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to clone it *each loop*, otherwise you just move the clone from parent to parent.

E.g.:

```
(function ($) {
    var $game1 = $('div#game1');
    var $frame = $('div.frame');

    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        $frame.clone().appendTo($game1);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I did that in your fiddle, and it works, but it doesn't *look* like it works because of some style stuff: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utZRJ/5/)

It's important that the code above is in a script tag **after** the elements on which it operates, because that code runs immediately. In your Fiddle, that happens because you're using jsFiddle's brain-dead *surprising* default setting which puts your code in an `window#load` handler. On your real page, you may need to make sure the `script` tag is *after* the elements. (Or use [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready), but you don't have to do that if you control where the `script` tags go.)

Comment: Thanks for help :). looks like  adeneo was right. My `script` tag was in `head`. I usually take care of such things but in this case i totally missed it. And this was my first time using `.clone()` so I assumed that I am doing something wrong. **One question**: So the value in clone remains same no matter what happens to original element?

Comment: @Sourabh: Yes, the clone is a separate element with the same properties. On the scripts, best not to put scripts in the `head`. More: [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

Comment: My code copies `div.frame` one time only. http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/utZRJ/6/ Now how is that happening? Sorry I am really confused about caching clone.

Comment: This `$game1.append($('div.frame').eq(0).clone());` works but this `$game1.append(frameClone);` doesn't, where `var frameClone = $('div.frame').eq(0).clone();` Why? http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/utZRJ/7/

Comment: @Sourabh: Sorry, I don't understand the question. The above clones the frame 8 times (resulting in 9 total). What's the problem?

Comment: Line 6 of JS of fiddle works but line 7 doesn't. If you comment line 6 and un-comment line 7, it copies it only 1 time (total 2). Like Here: http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/utZRJ/8/  How's this happening ?

Comment: @Sourabh: I gave you a proper working example above. The problem with your latest fiddle is the same as your original problem: You're only cloning it *once* (on line 3), and then reusing the **same clone** in the loop (line 7). So you end up moving that element. Look at the working example I gave you.

Comment: Ok so when I append, it just gets moved but `frameClone` still refers to that cloned and next append again moves it. I'm sorry this moving thing is a bit new to me. I understand it now. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Sourabh: Yes, that's it exactly!

Answer (score 2):

You have to clone it *each loop*

```
(function ($) {
    var $game1 = $('div#game1');

    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        var frameClone = $('div.frame').first().clone();
        frameClone.appendTo($game1);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

And if you really want to shorten it up:

```
(function ($) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) $('div.frame').first().clone().appendTo($('#game1'));
})(jQuery);
```

## jsFiddle

Comment: You don't need the clone outside the loop

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simplified version that runs properly, you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/utZRJ/2/

```
var $game1 = $('div#game1');
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    $('div.frame').eq(0).clone().appendTo($game1);
}
```

Comment: That's going to come handy some day :)